# Holding Sftp connection open inside camel component and route

Tags: sftp, apache-camel, jsch

I've written a Camel (2.10) component to do Sftp as I needed a bit more control over the connection than the out of the box component offers.

I have route that looks something like this:

```
from("direct:start")
    .to(startProcessor())       //1. Start processor sets the connection parameters for myCustomSftpComp producer
    .to("myCustomSftpComp")     //2. Uses Jsch, connects to server, gets the file, add to exchange, closes connection
    .to(somePostProcessor())    //3. Does something with the file
    .to("file://....");         //4. Write the file
```

This all works perfectly well.

My problem is at step 2, at the moment my files are quite small and I buffer them into memory, add the byte array to the Exchange body and its passed along and processed until it gets written by the file endpoint.

Of course this wont be sustainable with a large file, I need to add the InputStream reference to the exchange instead. My problem is I close and clean up the connection to the server inside myCustomSftpComp so when the exchange gets to post processor and file endpoint, it can no longer be accessed.

So basically I need some way to keep the connection open until after the file is written and closing the server connection inside the component from the route definition, sounds untidy so I'm open to atlernative ways of doing this.

Comment: Is it a requirement to close the connection each time, eg at the end of the route? If you leave the connection open, then step2 will reuse previous connection (if its still connected). So you can set disconnect=false.

Comment: @Claus - Resource usage on the target server is a concern, so I need to be sure connections are cleaned up properly hence the current implementation. If I leave the connection open at step 2 is there any way ensure to closes it after the route has finished its work i.e. after step 3 or 4?

Comment: You would need to extend the camel ftp component (eg the producer) and move the session close logic into a on completion on the exchange, eg I think we do a bit like that in the mail component, check the mail consumer. Then that logic will be executed when the exchange is complete, eg after step 4.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you've written your own SFTP component as the regular FTP component handles SFTP out of the box.

Passing just the input stream will still have you passing around the content in memory if you are going to do some processing in step three. Especially, this will be a problem since an InputStream can only be read once (although StreamCaching can be enabled, but is memory consuming).

What the FTP component can do is to download the file locally to a temporary file at disk. Then pass around the File handle to it. From that one, you could easily get Streams to do things with it as well as write it to a new file once done.

Check this out:
http://camel.apache.org/ftp2.html#FTP2-UsingLocalWorkDirectory

Comment: Its not a naive choice to create a custom component for this, I extensively tested the FTP/SFTP components for my use cases and found them to be too slow (mainly due to the high volumes of files I'm dealing with and the polling consumer), secondly as I said in my post I need absolute control over the connections as my component also has some load balancing policies built into it. I'll investigate using the local work directory again and see if it fits in the solution.

Comment: Sure, I'm sure there are reasons. As you say, the behaviours of SFTP/FTP varies a lot from use case to use case.

Anyway, Claus answer about moving the session handling to the life cycle of the exchange seems like the way to go